# How to display data with a specific property value in d3.js only on click/hover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a parallel coordinates plot visualized [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gty1996/pxn1Lu8s/11/).

What I want to do is visualize the data of type dataset2 only when hovering over the lines of dataset1.

So, I don't want the data that have this attribute     `"dataset": "dataset2",` to be shown initially only when clicking over a line of the same `type` e.g. bmw.

for example:

```
 {
    "type": "bmw",
    "dataset": "dataset1",
    "car1": 0.1068310912868661,
    "car2": 0.10347688576554598,
    "car3": 0.11709226547153888
  },
    {
    "type": "bmw",
    "dataset": "dataset2",
    "car1": 0.5068310912868661,
    "car2": 0.30347688576554598,
    "car3": 0.21709226547153888
  },
```

from these two datapoints I want only the first one to be shown in the plot. And when I click or hover over the first datapoint the other one to appear.

I am struggling to add this feature in my d3 visualization, so any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

P.S.
To hide it first I tried something like this but even this doesn't work.

```
// remove dataset2 data
data.filter(function(d) { return d.dataset == "dataset2"; })
    .each(function (d) {
        if (d.dataset == "dataset2" ) {
            this.hide();
            //this.remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I believe you can hide it by setting opacity to 0

Comment: can you show an example please? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set opacity during the time when you are adding groups "g".
You can check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/qL0gk5vj/) to understand the concept.

I have changed these lines of codes:

CSS:

```
    .hidder {
      opacity: 0 !important;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
    // USE THE COLOR SCALE TO SET THE STROKE BASED ON THE DATA
    foreground = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "foreground")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(Data)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", draw)
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
            var company = d.type.slice(0, d.type.indexOf(' '));
            return color(company);
        })
      .classed("hidder", function(d){
        if(d.dataset=="dataset2"){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
      });
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but am sorry I cannot see any difference in the chart? I still have all the lines plotted at the start just like before.